# Content inside linear layout is not showing

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to generate a table layout inside a linear layout and anything I put inside the second layout does not shows up. I'm trying to do something like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gnk3plt0ci3d2u8/tabla.png?dl=0

http://pastebin.com/USMrxJSn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width and height property that you have set to the inner Linear Layout causes the problem for you. Actually the values are shown but are not visible to you.

I would recommend you to use weightsem property to control the width of the layout.

Try the code below and I hope that should work for you.

**Code..**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".LinearLayout" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:padding="20dp" >

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="Emma Watson" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="Calorias" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="CO2" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="Distancia" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```